# HTML efficiency, best practices

Tags: performance, html, load

In the past, I created some divs to act like articles. Now I am thinking about changing it to HTML5 tag *article*...

Is there an important diference (in terms of efficiency) between using HTML elements or using equivalent divs created by the user?
For example: Will the browser load the pages faster if they are built only with HTML elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: maybe, if it will decrease the amount of markup you use. But not likely.

The benefit of using semantic tags is to add more meaning to the markup, not improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

May be. When you cretae a div and add styling to it, the browser needs to first interpret the element and then process the style over it and render it. If you use the appropriate HTML element, it would put less burden on the rendering engine.

Comment: But you'll still have to style the element. Moreover, elements like `article` being 'purely semantic' means the browser shouldn't have any default styling for them.